# How to create a decorator that adds a single function to the component class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decorator, ecmascript-next

I should preface this by saying I understand very little about es7 decorators. Basically what I want is a decorator called `@model` that adds a function to a component called `model`. So for example I'd call it like

```
@model class FooBar extends Component { }
```

and then the FooBar class would now have the model function.

Here's what I tried:

**Model.js**

```
export default function reactModelFactory( ctx ){

    return (key)=>{
        return {
            onChange: (e)=>ctx.setState({[key]:e.target.value}),
            value: ctx.state[key],
            name: key
        };
    };

};

function modelDecorator() {
    return function(ctx){
        return class extends ctx{
            constructor(...args){
                super(...args);
                this.model = reactModelFactory(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

export { modelDecorator as model };
```

**Login.js**

```
import React,{PureComponent} from 'react';
import {model} from './Model';

@model class Login extends PureComponent{}
```

React throws with error message:

> TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

I have no idea what this means. I'm looking for some help in getting my decorator working, and a bonus would be to understand the concept of decorators at all.

Comment: FYI, this is not ES7, this is a rejected syntax proposal, so it's relying on a deprecated legacy babel transform, to my understanding.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's good to know Patrick, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @dfsq's answer (I'm assuming it does what you want), you can go a step further in terms of interface performance by adding `model()` to the `prototype` instead of to each instance like this:

```
export default function reactModelFactory() {
  return function model (key) {
    return {
      onChange: (e) => this.setState({ [key]: e.target.value }),
      value: this.state[key],
      name: key
    };
  };
};

function modelDecorator(Class) {
  Object.defineProperty(Class.prototype, 'model', {
    value: reactModelFactory(),
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });

  return Class;
}
```

This is much better for performance as it causes the decorator to modify the existing class's `prototype` a single time with the `model` member method, rather than attaching a scoped copy of the `model` method within the anonymous extended class's `constructor` each time a new instance is constructed.

To clarify, this means that in @dfsq's answer, `reactModelFactory()` is invoked each time a new instance is constructed, while in this answer, `reactModelFactory()` is only invoked a single time when the decorator is activated on the class.

The reason I used `configurable` and `writable` in the [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) is because that's how the `class { }` syntax natively defines member methods on the `prototype`:

```js
class Dummy {
  dummy () {}
}

let {
  configurable,
  writable,
  enumerable
} = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Dummy.prototype, 'dummy');

console.log('configurable', configurable);
console.log('enumerable', enumerable);
console.log('writable', writable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your model decorator should not return new function. `ctx` will be passed to `modelDecorator` itself. So you really just need to return newly extended class from it:

```
function modelDecorator(ctx) {
  return class extends ctx {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      this.model = reactModelFactory(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Note, that the syntax you tried would work if your decorator was supposed to be used like this (Angular style decorators):

```
@model({ modelName: 'user' })
class Login extends PureComponent {}
```

Then you would need extra closure to keep passed parameters into your decorator:

```
function modelDecorator({ modelName }) {
  return (ctx) => {
    console.log('model name', modelName)
    return class extends ctx {
      constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.model = reactModelFactory(this);
      }
    }
  }
}
```